# method calling using classes in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to run this program but it is telling me that r is not found. How do you call the method since it is in a class? (I am assuming that the error is because of this)

```
package pack

class Sud(val grid: List[List[Int]]) {

  def r(r: Int): List[Int] =
  //code
}

object Sud
{
  def main(args: Array[String]) 
  {

     val puzzle=new Sudoku(List(
          List(0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0),
        //rest of Sudoku puzzle created by repeating the above statement

          println(r(0)) //ERROR given here
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a *class method*, so you need an instance of a class to call it. If you want free-functions, you will have to put them in an `object` and import said `object`.

Answer (score 11):

As said in the comments, in your code `r` is a class method. Hence you need to **Instantiate** your Class `Sud` in order to call that method.

```
val inst: Sud = new Sud(puzzle)

println(inst.r(0))
```